# Typescript is giving error TS2411 on it's own Typescript module?

Tags: typescript, typescript2.0

I've switched to using @types (as one should in Typescript 2.0). So I ran `npm i -S typescript @types/typescript` to get `typescript` running all hunky dory.

However, now when I run `tsc` on my own project with `"exclude": ["node_modules"]`, I get the following error about 20 times (for different lines of the file).

```
node_modules/@types/typescript/index.d.ts(1306,9): error TS2411: Property
     'allowNonTsExtensions' of type 'boolean | undefined' is not assignable to
     string index type 'string | number | boolean'.
```

My code still runs fine, but it's forcing me to check whether or not the transpiling is actually wrong, or it's just these errors. Is there a way to prevent this "error" from occuring?

*edit - The more I think about it, do I even need `typescript` in my `node_modules`? Should it just be a global install?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Don't install `@types/typescript`. The `typescript` module contains everything it needs. Type definition files are already included in `typescript/lib` folder.

2) You should definitely have `typescript` installed globally, but if you want to share your project (e.g. on GitHub), you should install it also locally. People won't have problems about missing dependancies or version mismatches.